# decrypting aes ccm 128, mic 8bit, in C with openssl EVP

Tags: c, cryptography, openssl, aes

i need to decrypt aes 128 ccm with a mic of 8 bytes using openssl, but my output is always empty, here is my code:

```
void aes(){
unsigned char * aad = extochar("0841000CF635DFAB74F06D40A6A30090");


unsigned char * cipher = extochar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
//unsigned char * mic = extochar("8f3829e8e76ee23c04f566189e63c686");
int cipher_size  = strlen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
unsigned char * key = extochar("C7134FD10709F028D63C2E05CBB4C16C");
unsigned char * nonce = extochar("0074F06D40A6A3000000000011");
int nonce_size = strlen("0074F06D40A6A3000000000011")/2;

int aad_size = strlen("0841000CF635DFAB74F06D40A6A30090")/2;
unsigned char plain[cipher_size];
int mic_size = 8;

EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(ctx);

// Just set the alg
EVP_DecryptInit(ctx, EVP_aes_128_ccm(), 0, 0);

// Set nonce size
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_CCM_SET_IVLEN, nonce_size, 0);

// Set the tag from the end of the encrypted array
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_CCM_SET_TAG, mic_size, cipher +sizeof(unsigned char)*(cipher_size -8));

// Set key and nonce
EVP_DecryptInit(ctx, 0, key, nonce);

int outl = 0;
// We will encrypt Psize bytes
EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, 0, &outl, 0, cipher_size);

// Add AAD for verification
EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, 0, &outl, aad, aad_size);

// Time to decrypt the data into D
EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plain, &outl, cipher, cipher_size);

// Not sure if this is needed
EVP_DecryptFinal(ctx, &plain[outl], &outl);


int i;
printf("plaintext");
for(i=0; i<cipher_size; i++)
    printf("%.2x",plain[i]);
printf("\n");
```

the function extochar is the following:

```
char * extochar(char* string)
{
    unsigned char * out = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*strlen(string)/2);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(string)/2; i++)
    {
        sscanf(&string[2*i], "%02x", (unsigned int *)(&out[i]));
    }
    return out;
}
```

the plaintext should begin with

```
AA AA 03 00 00 00 08 00 45 00 01 A9 0F DC 40 00 40 06 E6 14 27 E9 64 63 D1 55 E5 BC 8F B4 14 6C
```

and the last test vector of  [this link](http://www.mail-archive.com/stds-p1619@listserv.ieee.org/msg00548/ccm.2) works (i tested only that one, changing EVP_aes_128_ccm() to EVP_aes_256_ccm() and mic size to 16)

what's wrong?
thanks a lot in advice!

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved GCM decryption in following steps. Please see if it can help you.

```
//Step 1: Set cipher.
retval  = EVP_DecryptInit (ctx, EVP_aes_128_gcm(), (const unsigned char *)key, (const unsigned char *)iv);
if(retval <= 0) {
   //Error
}

//Step 2: Set tag. Extract the tag from the message if required.
retval  = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl (ctx, EVP_CTRL_CCM_SET_TAG, taglen, (void *)tag);
if(retval <= 0) {
    //Error
}

//Step 3: Add AAD.
retval  = EVP_DecryptUpdate (ctx, NULL, (int *)&len, (const unsigned char *)add, (int)aadlen);
if(retval <= 0) {
    //Error
}

//Step 4: Decrypt the data.
buflen = 0;
retval  = EVP_DecryptUpdate (ctx, (unsigned char *)buf, (int *)&buflen, (const unsigned char *)inbuf, inbuflen);
if(retval <= 0) {
    //Error
}


//This step is necessary
//If this step fails, means authentication fails.
retval  = EVP_DecryptFinal(ctx, (unsigned char *)buf + buflen, (int *)&buflen);
if(retval <= 0) {
  //Error and discard the decrypted data so far.
}


//Clean up.
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup (ctx);
```